# Apollo client slow for large GraphQL response

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

The Apollo cache spends 1.2s parsing the result and putting it into the cache:
[image]

Things I've tried:

- `keyFields: false` to avoid normalisation
- `fetchPolicy: "no-cache"`
- `assumeImmutableResults: true`
- `canonizeResults: false`

Turning all this on should allow Apollo to dump the object directly into the cache without any further processing. Is there any way to achieve this? It looks like Apollo is trying to deep clone this huge object.

Comment: It looks like it's calling `writeToStore.js.StoreWriter.processFieldValue` recursively on the objects even though normalisation is disabled.

Comment: StoreWriter.writeToStore seems to be the entry point. I need to be able to run the write without traversing the whole object.